# Groovy - How to simplify embedded function arguments

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am running groovy in jenkins and I want to split the data from the functionality. I've tried to create a map with variable names and values but it looks like functions inside functions screws that up. I want to pull out CurrentBuildNo, ProjectName, Results_Folder (they are different for each parallel run) without duplicating code.

```
autotests = parallel (
  { ignore(ABORTED) { 
     retry ( 2 ) {
       build("AutoTest", CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ProjectName: params["ProjectName"], Results_Folder: Results_Folder) 
   } } },
  { ignore(ABORTED) { 
     retry ( 2 ) {
       build("AutoTest", CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ProjectName: params["ProjectName"], Results_Folder: Results_Folder) 
   } } }
)
```

The logic I want is something like:

```
tests = {{CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ...},{CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ...}}
autotests = parallel (
  for (i in tests){
     ignore(ABORTED) { 
        retry ( 2 ) {
           build("AutoTest", test[i]['CurrentBuildNo'], test[i]['ProjectName']...) 
      } } }
  }
)
```

Comment: What does _"functions inside functions screws that up"_ mean?  What have you tried?  How did that fail?  What would your ideal solution look like?

Comment: I'm not sure of how I would write the syntax for the second code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, I *think* you'll want something like this:

```
def tests = [ [ CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ... ],
              [ CurrentBuildNo: CurrentBuildNo, ... ] ]

parallel tests.collect { t ->
    {
        ignore( ABORTED ) {
            retry( 2 ) {
                build( 'AutoTest', t.CurrentBuildNo, ... )
            }
        }
    }
}
```